# Can a Gray Rain Cloak be refilled?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, feywild

The *Gray Rain Cloak* is made from Feywild rain using a minor ritual. Players can stretch it on the ground and take out water from it, but this "depletes" the cloak and makes it shorter every time. Could it be refilled say, using mundane rainwater or jars of Feywild rainwater saved for this purpose? Or would the cloak be destroyed in the attempt?

One of my players asked me this because the father of his PC gave him that cloak, and he doesn't want to buy another. Truth is he's just stingy, but still managed to get me into a pinch.

Comment: D&D 4e doesn't much care to go into the details of its items in practical, non-rules terms. This might very well be entirely up to you.

Answer (score 10):

**No free refills...**

RAW there is no listed way to replenish the cloak once it starts being used.

From the Compendium:

> created through the performance of a minor ritual. The garment looks and feels like a normal wool cloak, except that it keeps its wearer completely dry in the rain. When the cloak is spread out on the ground, it becomes a puddle of pure rainwater. You can turn the pool back into a cloak again by grabbing the water (a minor action), or water can be taken from the pool using a cup or a similar vessel. Doing so gradually uses up the cloak’s material, making it shorter every time it reverts to a garment, until nothing is left of it after 2 gallons of its water are consumed.

The item entry explicitly states that it is used up (in part or full) whenever water is taken from it, and in addition to no mention of replenishment, explicitly states that once 2 gallons of water is consumed that it is gone. Since it is a magical object created by a ritual, vs. a true magic item in D&D I would say that it just wears out through use and a new one must be created via the minor ritual again.

Answer (score 10):

Rules-as-written, there's no way to recharge the [Gray Rain Cloak](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=364). However, I think it would be reasonable to allow rainwater to restore the cloak.

Firstly, it's an inexpensive item with no combat benefit. Its abilities to protect from rain and turn into a puddle are purely narrative, except for one: it lets you carry 2 gallons of water weighing 16.7 pounds in item weighing only 3 pounds.

The ritual [Make Whole](https://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=51) lets you repair items for 20% of the base cost, or 4 gp in this case. That benchmarks our repair value at 5 sp per quart of water. That's so cheap as to be negligible.

I'd recommend requiring rainwater to recharge it, rather than just any water. It fits thematically and means you have to refill the cloak outside the dungeon, which makes it an interesting limited resource.

Comment: Since it's Feywild rain initially I'd put a further limitation on the houserule, something like rain during a full moon "because the Feywild is closer to the mundane world then" or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

The *Grey Rain Cloak* is created through the performance of a minor, undescribed ritual.
Like many others in the game, rituals are used to provide different commodities, from summoning spirits to improving mounts to - in this case - creating a cloak from rainwater.

Since most magic items can be crafted with a ritual, we can easily figure out by comparison the price of the undescribed ritual needed to craft the cloak. The description of the cloak itself tells us which additional conditions are needed.
I'll leave to you the homebrewing of this new ritual, according to your own tastes and balance needs.

There's a second problem, though, and it's that this peculiar cloak is supposed to be important for the character, being a gift from his father.
You could essentially go two ways.

Since the cloak is not listed under magic items, have the Make Whole ritual being able to restore it; or homebrew a new ritual that can refill (at a price proportionate to the missing lenght) the cloak.

Should you choose this last option, carefully consider that your stingy player is not going to be happy if you price this ritual so high that refilling let's say 50% of the cloak costs more than 50% of making a new one; while a ritual that allows for refilling instead of crafting anew should probably cost a little more for the improved utility.

@DampeS8N makes me notice how you could use the crafting ritual flavoring it as a refill. The same cost-advantage considerations apply.

Comment: however, nothing stops you from paying the full cost of the ritual and flavoring it as a refill.